# i am making a vending machine but js error: NaN

Tags: javascript

```
`var y = 0 ;
var x = 0;
function atm(num1, num2){
console.log((num1 - num2));
return num1 - num2 ;
}
var items =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function vm(y, x){
if( atm(y , items[x]) < 0  ){
    result = "U Do not have enough money to pay";
}
else if ( atm(y , items[x]) === 0  );{
    result = "Ur money just matches the required paying fee";
}
if ( atm(y , items[x]) > 0  );{
    result="U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder";
}
}

vm(2, 3);`
```

**the error is that  it gives me 3 answers as u can see:
\\
-2

"U Do not have enough money to pay"

"Ur money just matches the required paying fee"

-2

"U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder"
\\

\\ 
also the 3rd result "  result="U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder" " wont show the remainder

"y goes to the amount of money u hold"

"x goes to the number of items from array"

vm is the vending machine and what it should do is show 1 answer of these up

1- u do not have enough money to pay

2- Ur money just matches the required paying fee

3- is that he has more money and he will reserve " y - items[x] " as remainder

**Please when u got my error write me the error and the full code, sometimes it gets hard on me, im still new...**

Comment: I've removed your question's Java tag since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming in this language.

Comment: please add what `atm` should do and what `vm` should do. and what `x` and `y`mean, beside of `items`.

Comment: for obvious reasons.. you need to return num1-num2 from atm function instead of doing a console.log here

Comment: This is so poor. You don't even call the atm function with the two required parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your if statement 
change this :

```
if( atm(y - items[x]) < 0  ){ ... }
else if ( atm(y - items[x]) === 0  );{ ... }
if ( atm(y - items[x]) > 0  );{ ... }
```

to this :

```
if( atm(y , items[x]) < 0  ){ ... }
else if ( atm(y , items[x]) == 0  ){ ... }
if ( atm(y , items[x]) > 0  ){ ... }
```

and this :

```
function atm(num1, num2){
    console.log(num1 - num2);
}
```

to this :

```
function atm(num1, num2){
    return (num1 - num2);
}
```

final code :

```
var y = 0 ;
var x = 0;
function atm(num1, num2){
        return (num1 - num2);
    }

var items =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function vm(y, x){
if( atm(y , items[x]) < 0  ){
    result = "U Do not have enough money to pay";
}
else if ( atm(y , items[x]) === 0  ){
    result = "Ur money just matches the required paying fee";
}
if ( atm(y , items[x]) > 0  ){
    result="U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you do not return anything from your function `atm` and second you call it with 1 parameter instead of 2 so the subtraction results in NaN

For example you call it like so with only 1 parameter

```
if (atm(y - items[x]) > 0) ...
```

As I don't know what your code is supposed to do I can't fix it for you but I think you should be able to do that once you understand the problems with your code

Answer (score 1):

## 2 Mistakes :

1. `function atm(num1, num2)`  should end up with `return` .
2. `atm(y , items[x]) < 0` instead of `atm(y - items[x]) < 0`

## Right Code :

```js
var y = 0 ;
var x = 0;
function atm(num1, num2){
    console.log((num1 - num2));
    return num1 - num2
}
var items =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]//Array.from({length:10},(v,k)=>k+1);
function vm(y, x){
    if( atm(y , items[x]) < 0  ){
        console.log('U Do not have enough money to pay');
    }
    else if ( atm(y , items[x]) === 0  );{
        console.log("Ur money just matches the required paying fee");
    }
    if ( atm(y , items[x]) > 0  );{
        console.log("U will reserve atm(y, items[x]) as a remainder");
    }
}
vm(2, 1);
```